# mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin

alguien sabe como solucionar estos errores en phpmyadmin.

[image: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) La conexión para controluser, como está definida en su configuración, fracasó.]

Comment: Se está intentando entrar en la base de datos con un usuario llamado `phpmyadmin` el cual o no existe, o no tiene permisos o su contraseña es inválida. ¿Podrías revisar eso y además mostrar el código con el que intentas conectar (desde `index.php` supongo) o el archivo de configuración? No dices nada sobre el contexto de tu conexión.

Comment: Hola mas adelantes actualizo los datos de la pregunta, gracias por contestar.